# Button Submit for Review is disabled

Tags: app-store-connect

I did everything correctly, but the button is always enabled. I also downloaded a new bundle, changed the screenshots, but the button remained unchanged. How can I fix it?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

App submission is disabled until Dec 30.

https://itunespartner.apple.com/en/apps/faq/Managing%20Your%20Apps_Submission%20Process#68611491

Comment: But today I downloaded the new version and made for Review, but I had to change one thing in the app so I downloaded the new bundle and it has become inaccessible!